# Subscribe arrayChange on knockout computed accessor

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have a case where I need to listen for array changes of a computed that is simply returning a filtered value of an observable.
However, I do need to have the full list of changes, as **.subscribe(function(changes){},null,'arrayChange')** would do on an **observableArray**.

What I understand is that **arrayChange** does not work in the case of a computed value, because it probably remakes a new array and so there's no specific change to list.

See http://jsfiddle.net/darknessm0404/A6D8u/1/ for a complete example.

```
// The following does not work, but I'd like it
computedTest.subscribe(function(changesList){
    console.log('COMPUTED subscription : arrayChange');
}, null, 'arrayChange');
```

The only way I seem to achieve what I want is to create another observable array which would have push/delete depending on the changes, so I would be able to get the 'arrayChange' method work.

Full example of my idea:

```
this.events.listFiltered = ko.observableArray().extend({ rateLimit: 0 });
this.events.listFiltered_Worker = ko.computed(function () {
    var listFiltered = me.events.listFiltered();

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(me.events.list(), function (item) {
            index = listFiltered.indexOf(item);
        if (FILTERING_CASE_HERE) {
            if (index < 0) {
                listFiltered.push(item);
            }
        } else if (index >= 0) { // Delete
            listFiltered.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(me.events.list(), function (item) {
        return !(item.end().isBefore(filterStart) || item.start().isAfter(filterEnd));
    });
    return __rd++;
}).extend({ rateLimit: 0 });
this.events.listFiltered.subscribe(function () {
    debug('inside subscribe');
    debugger;
}, null, 'arrayChange');
```

However I was wondering if there's a easier solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout supports `arrayChange` for any observable, which you have to enable specifically.

```
var computedTest = ko.computed(function() {  
    ...
}).extend({trackArrayChanges: true});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/A6D8u/2/

If you look at the Knockout source code, [this is what's done](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/f2d4cdd9e9b04a3fb8ce4b9491126b093c24a7e1/src/subscribables/observableArray.js#L9) automatically for observable arrays.

If this a common scenario in your project you could create a wrapper function that does this:

```
function computedArray() {
    return ko.computed.apply(ko, arguments).extend({trackArrayChanges: true});
}
```

Comment: Deleted my misleading answer. I really forgot about the extender. We should probably revisit our docs to ensure that this is adequately covered for everyone.